# Should I declare all members/function that doesn't throw noexcept?

Tags: c++, c++11, exception, constants, noexcept

One of the [CppCoreGuidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Re-no-throw-codes) is E.12: Use noexcept when exiting a function because of a throw is impossible or unacceptable.
Does it mean that I should declare noexcept on every member and functions that don't throw exceptions and doesn't call other methods/functions that throw? I know it's a good prevaricate to always declare const as much as possible, and I see a lot of const methods in different projects, but I haven't seen noexcept used that much.

Answer (score 2):

> Should I declare all members/function that doesn't throw noexcept?

This answer will not attempt to answer whether this is a good practice or not (opinionated), but note that the practice is common when working with safety-critical C++ development, and stricter C++ Guidelines commonly *require* that all declarations of non-throwing functions contain the [`noexcept` specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec).

### AUTOSAR C++14 Guidelines

As an example, Rule A15-4-4 from the [*Guidelines for the use of the C++14 language in critical and safety-related systems*](https://www.autosar.org/fileadmin/user_upload/standards/adaptive/17-03/AUTOSAR_RS_CPP14Guidelines.pdf) from AUTOSAR (an inofficial but from the industry de facto successor of [MISRA C++:2008](https://www.misra.org.uk/Publications/tabid/57/Default.aspx#label-cpp)) covers this practice along with a rationale:

> **Rule A15-4-4** (required, implementation, automated)
>
> A declaration of non-throwing function shall contain noexcept specification.
>
> **Rationale**
>
> Noexcept specification is a method for a programmer to inform the
> compiler whether or not a function should throw exceptions. The
> compiler can use this information to enable certain optimizations on
> non-throwing functions as well as enable the noexcept operator, which
> can check at compile time if a particular expression is declared to
> throw any exceptions.
>
> Noexcept specification is also a method to inform other programmers
> that a function does not throw any exceptions.
>
> A non-throwing function needs to declare noexcept specifier.
> A function that may or may not throw exceptions depending on a template
> argument, needs to explicitly specify its behavior using
> noexcept() specifier.
>
> Note that it is assumed that a function which does not contain
> explicit noexcept specification throws exceptions, similarly to
> functions that declare noexcept(false) specifier.

The *required* tag is applied to rules are required to fulfill if the code base is to be claimed to fulfill compliance to the guideline:

> #### 5.1.2 Rule classification according to obligation level
>
> **required:** these are mandatory requirements placed on the code. C++ code that is claimed to conform to AUTOSAR C++14 shall comply with
> every “Required” rule. Formal deviations must be raised where this is
> not the case.

Naturally it is up to the particular company/supplier to decide whether and how to comply with AUTOSAR C++14, but it is common that an [OEM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Original_equipment_manufacturer) require compliance to a particular conding standard, e.g. for C++ MISRA C++:2008 or AUTOSAR C++14, and deviations from particular rules commonly need to go through a formal deviation process.

The *automated* tag is applied to rules that can easily be automatically enforced by means of static analysis.

Comment: One problem with such a rule is that it blindly codifies coincidence, promoting it into the interface, strangling future development.

Comment: Guidelines don't require anything in safety critical development.   Safety standards require that there be evidence, to an appropriate level of technical rigour, that the system behaves as required.    Guidelines like you cite are designed to make it easier to provide that justification.   But, equally, the guidelines can be ignored - either entirely or on a case-by-case basis - if there is a suitable justification.   Some regulatory or policy frameworks may make it mandatory to follow guidelines but, otherwise, guidelines are advisory, not mandatory.

Comment: @Deduplicator I will not (nor does my answer) place any opinionated view on whether the various stricter rules of safety-critical C++ development guidelines are sound or not.

Comment: @Peter As per Section 5.1.2 of the AUTOSAR C++ Guidelines (which has similar requirements in MISRA C++:2008): _**required**: these are **mandatory requirements** placed on the code. C++ code that **is claimed to conform to** AUTOSAR C++14 **shall comply with every “Required” rule**. Formal deviations must be raised where this is not the case."_. Naturally it is up to the particular company/supplier to decide whether and how to comply with AUTOSAR C++14, but many OEM's require compliance to e.g. MISRA / AUTOSAR, and deviations from particular rules need to go through a formal deviation process.

Comment: @deduplicator: That is the difference between consumer grade software and safe software. According to ISO26262, Part 6, table 9, Static code analysis is mandatoror starting with ASIL B. But even for ASIL QM it should be preformed. The qualified tools PcLintPlus, Coverity and Polyspace inform you about that problem. This must be fixed. So, maybe remember that when you next time drive a car with steer or brake by wire . . . For consumer grade code everything is OK. Who cares?

Comment: I doubt exceptions are even turned on in car control software. Heck, it's probably not even C++.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings For car _control_ software, agreed. A restrictive and less complex approach may be to entirely ban exceptions and thus not need to apply any of the related rules of AUTOSAR C++14 regarding exceptions. A large part of non-control AD software (say, sensor fusion, vision etc), is statistical in nature, and the statistically-dependent nominal performance may typically be safety-critical itself. In these scenarios, SOTIF (and heavy verification) may be more appropriate to turn to rather than to attempt to apply ISO26262 from a _safety performance_ perspective. ...

Comment: ... In these kind of contexts, exceptions may even become viable (supplier/OEM choice), as emphasis would be placed on _degradation_ for the cases where a _transition to a safe state_ is needed (as compared to "never go into an unsafe state", which may be plausible for more deterministic control software).

Comment: @ArminMontigny Automated analysis can often prove that a property is (not) satisfied by an implementation, but cannot divine whether that's coincidence or design. As I said, if you are happy to promote coincidence to contract, that's easy enough, but has its disadvantages.

Comment: Oh cool, some of the people here are AFuSa Experts. I wouldn't have exptected that. Others are not . . .

Answer (score 1):

You should declare every function which cannot or should not throw *by design* `noexcept`.
No more, no less.

Remember that consumers cannot *know* your intentions unless you spell them out, and they will rely on what you write. That is not to detract from there being hordes of them trying to muddle through without reading anything.

If you codify coincidence, you paint yourself into a corner, and will struggle to improve on the implementation.
If you fail to codify your contract, consumers will have to devine it from the implementation, and they *will* read more into it than you intended, painting you into a corner (again).

That is not to say that there aren't rules and guidelines out there which mistake coincidence (some property does (not) hold) with intent (some property should / must not hold).